# Is that possible to use one-column layout for lightning home page layout?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, home-page-component, home-page-layout, lightning-home-page

We are trying to remove sidebar from default home page layout.

I have even tried to create App Page, copy App Page single column layout and substitute the code of Home Page by it and then deploy it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>Component</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>main</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>Home Page Default</masterLabel>
    <template>
        <name>flexipage:defaultAppHomeTemplate</name>
    </template>
    <type>HomePage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

but when I tried to deploy it this failed with error

> *********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED *********** All Component Failures:
>   1.  flexipages/Home_Page_Default.flexipage -- Error: You can't use template flexipage:defaultAppHomeTemplate with page type HomePage.
>
> *********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********

Is that possible at all to use one-column layout for lightning home page layout?

If this is possible then how do I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is [an option but available only in Winter'18 release](https://patlatus.wordpress.com/2017/10/04/salesforce-winter-18-feature-to-customize-lightning-home-page-layout/).

You need to create the following component `HomePageSingleColumnTemplate` with the following code

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:homeTemplate">
    <aura:attribute name="main" type="Aura.Component[]" /> 

    <div>
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread">
            {!v.main}
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Also you have to specify design for it

```
<design:component >
    <flexipage:template >
        <flexipage:region name="main" defaultWidth="Xlarge">
        </flexipage:region>
    </flexipage:template>
</design:component>
```

You might or might not specify an icon for it, you can read [interface description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces_lightning_hometemplate.htm?search_text=home%20page) and [advanced configuration guide here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm?search_text=flexipage:region) about how to specify an icon or image for your template.

Then you just need to create a new Lightning Home page based on created layout and you will see one column.

So now the flexiPage would look like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>Component</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>main</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>Home Page Default</masterLabel>
    <template>
        <name>HomePageSingleColumnTemplate</name>
    </template>
    <type>HomePage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```